# Resizing UIButton with image as backgrond for different iPhones

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios-autolayout

Let's say I have a few UIButtons that I created initially for the iPhone 5, and now i want to scale them correctly to work with iPhone 6 and 6 plus.

http://oi60.tinypic.com/2poec5j.jpg

How would I go about using autolayout to properly scale and fill the width of say an iPhone 6 and 6 Plus with the button? (Using Sign Up with Facebook in above image as example) I assume I have to make bigger versions of this image? I would rather not have the image get distorted in anyway. If so how much bigger would I have to make them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty good tutorials here (1 YouTube, 1 web) on autolayout:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng

http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/

In regards to your image size, if you have a base size for a nonRetina, then you @2x for retina and @3x for the full iOS 7/iOS 8 designs.  If already sizing for retina than make one for @1.5x.  You can also have the @1.5x used for the smaller size if you just give 1 image.

Answer (score 1):

You don't resize your buttons for iPhone 6. The design idea is that your UI primitives like buttons stay the same size. They use graphics assets that are higher resolution for the higher resolution displays (as explained by MinnesotaSteve) but the buttons and such should stay the same size.

You might make a table view display more rows, or make the rows wider so you can see more text, but buttons would say the same size (in points)

Comment: But if my buttons stayed the same size, as they do in the above image for the Sign in with Facebook button, it doesn't fill the width of the screen for each device. So wouldn't I have to make either 1 image that is for the 6 plus and scale it down, or multiple images such as a signin, signin@2x and signin@3x? I also saw an option for aspect ratio?  Maybe that has something to do with it

Comment: Buttons shouldn't be the whole width of the screen.